# Enable brace expansion on RET and SPC in doom-emacs in :lang go

Tags: go, emacs

Currently in doom-emacs brace expansion on RET and SPC is not enabled in `:lang go`. I've tried to enable it, but without success, with the below code

```lisp
(after! smartparens
  (sp-local-pair '(go-mode) "{" nil :post-handlers '(:add ("||\n[i]" "RET") ("| " "SPC"))))
```

How can I enable brace expansion on RET and SPC for doom-emacs in `:lang go`?